# Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer::AddAddres() in /home4/pmartinez/public_html/aplicacion/php/form.php on line 74

Tags: php, phpmailer

I can't send a mail with attachment file, I generate my file with `fpdf`, my file is created correctly, because it appears in my created files, but I have this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer::AddAddres() in
>   /home4/pmartinez/public_html/aplicacion/php/form.php on line 74

this is my `form.php`:

```html
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $fecha = $_POST['Fecha'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $programa = $_POST['programa'];
    $monto = $_POST['monto'];
    $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
    $datos = $_POST['datos'];

    $cuerpo = "Fecha de Emisión de Pago: " . $fecha;
    $cuerpo .= "Ln(10)";
    $cuerpo .= "Nombre del Alumno que pago: " . $nombre;
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Programa Inscrito: " . $programa;
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Monto Pagado: Q" . $monto;
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Tipo de Pago: " . $tipo;
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Persona que Atendio: " . $datos;

    require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10, "Fecha de Emision de Pago: ". $fecha);
    $pdf->Ln(10);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10, "Nombre del Alumno que pago: " . $nombre);
    $pdf->Ln(10);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10, "Programa Inscrito: " . $programa);
    $pdf->Ln(10); 
    $pdf->Cell(40,10, "Monto Pagado: Q" . $monto);
    $pdf->Ln(10);     
    $pdf->Cell(40,10, "Tipo  de Pago: " . $tipo);
    $pdf->Ln(10);   
    $pdf->Cell(40,10, "Quien Atendio: " . $datos);
    $pdf->Ln(10);   
    $pdf->Output('F','Recibo.pdf');

    include ("class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    //utilizaremos un servidor SMTP
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->CharSet="UTF-8";
    //autenticacion
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Username = "maynor@eade.org.es";
    $mail->Password = "maynor123";
    $mail->Port = 587;
    //quien envia
    $mail->From = "maynor@eade.org.es";
    $mail->FromName = "EADE Escuela de Negocios";
    //a quien enviamos
    $mailTo=$email;
    $nameTo=$nombre;
    //cuerpo en html
    $contenidoHTML="<head>";
    $contenidoHTML.="<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">";
    $contenidoHTML.="</head><body>";
    $contenidoHTML.="<b>Constancia de pago adjunta.</b>";
    $contenidoHTML.="</body>\n";
    //contenido en texto
    $contenidoTexto = "Constancia de pago adjunta.";
    $mail->Subject="Contancia de Pago";
    //adjuntando archivo
    $rutaAbsoluta=substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"],0,strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"],"/"));
    $mail->AddAttachment($rutaAbsoluta."/", "Recibo.php");
    $mail->MsgHTML($contenidoHTML);
    $mail->AddAddres($email, $nombre);
    $mail->Send();



 echo "<script language='javascript'> 
            
            window.location.href='../index.html';

            </script>";

   }
?>
```

and this is the `line #74`:

```html
        $mail->AddAddres($email, $nombre);
```

I'm a bit new to php, can you help me please? Thanks!

Comment: I have't used PHPMailer, but that method should probably be `AddAddress`, right? [Also](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php): "Function names are case-insensitive, though it is usually good form to call functions as they appear in their declaration."

Comment: Yup, He spelled it wrong and the next parameter should be the name of the recipient

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499642/how-to-fix-undefined-method-phpmaileraddadress-error/36499749

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see PHPmailer code.And that function should be addAddress.You should type "$mail->addAddress()" .fix your typo